# How to fix Brew Install error. Xcode 8.3.3 outdated install Xcode 9.2 on High Sierra

Tags: xcode, homebrew

```
Error: Your Xcode (8.3.3) is too outdated.
Please update to Xcode 9.2 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how can I fix the error and install things using brew. It gives error whenever I try to install anything using brew. It tells me to update my Xcode.

Comment: Maybe update to Xcode 9.2 (or delete it)?

Comment: deleted it and it got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

sudo xcode-select --switch /path/to/new/xcode